# Java CreateProcess Error in Windows 7 UAC

Tags: java, windows-7, uac

I'm not able to programatically launch an Exe on a Windows 7 64-bit workstation. If UAC is off then the Exe will be launched from the bean. If UAC is on then the java console reports `CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation`.

A java bean is launching the Exe on the workstation using

```
Process p = rt.exec(args);

Have also the ProcessBuilder class.
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", m_sProg, m_sParams});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your .exe seems to be requiring elevation via embedded manifest. To start it, you have to use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153.aspx) or [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154.aspx) WinAPI function.

You can try to overcome this restriction by using `start` command:

```
new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", "start", m_sProg, m_sParams});
```

---

If you can change the .exe your launching, then removing `requestedExecutionLevel` from the manifest might be an option unless the .exe really requires administrator privileges to run.